# Problema nombre autor en repositorio remoto

Tags: git, bitbucket

Estoy trabajando con *Git* en *MAC*, desde terminal y me aparece un nombre de autor diferente al esperado en el repositorio remoto cuando hago *pushes*.

He configurado mi nombre en la configuración global, del repositorio, del sistema de *Git*, como user.name y author.name y lo obtengo correctamente con los comandos:

```
git config author.name
git config user.name
git config -l
```

Si hago un *push* en remoto aparece como Autor: ***Master Account***.

Estoy usando ademas Vagrant boxes, si hago un *push* desde dentro de Vagrant, como autor aparece ***Vagrant***. Si cierro la conexión, suspendo las cajas, cierro la consola donde se estaban ejecutando, aparece ***Master Account***. Dentro de vagrant también configure las globales y me sigue apareciendo ***Vagrant*** en el remoto.

Tengo la clave SSH pública en *Bitbucket* por lo que *pusheo* sin que me pida contraseña. He probado en otra cuenta de bitbucket, metiendo usuario y contraseña para enviar los commits y sigue ocurriendo. También, He borrado las claves del llavero de MAC relacionadas con *git*, *bitbucket*...

¿Cómo hago para que aparezca ***MiNombre*** como autor en **Bitbucket**?

Answer (score 4):

¿Has configurado también el correo? En principio poniendo el mismo que tienes en bitbucket debería servirte.

**Configurar username/email de bitbucket**

```
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"

git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

**Configurar username/email para un repositorio específico**

```
git config user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"

git config user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

Verificalo en el archivo:

```
cat .git/config
```

Comment: Configurados usuario y email de forma global.
Si hago el **cat** que mencionas, no aparecen por ningún lado en el contenido mostrado

Comment: el cat solo funciona para el repositiorio específico, para ver las variables globales tienes que hacerlo como has dicho en la pregunta, con: `git config --get user.name` y `git config --get user.email`

Comment: es bueno saberlo